# node size and align

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I don't understand why the "idéation" node is larger than the 2 others "Sept." and "Oct."

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,scopes,positioning,backgrounds,shapes,fit,shadows,
calc}

\begin{document}
\noindent

\begin{tikzpicture}[background rectangle/.style={draw=blue!50,fill=blue!10,
      rounded corners=5pt, drop shadow},
    show background rectangle]
    \tikzset
    {
      arrow/.style=
      {
        draw,
        minimum height=10mm,
        minimum width=20mm,
        inner sep=0pt,
        shape=signal,
        signal from=west,
        signal to=east,
        signal pointer angle=110,
        top color=green!60!black!90!,
        bottom color=green!30,
        % fill=blue!50,
        drop shadow,
      },
      sign/.style={
      draw,
      minimum height=10mm,
      minimum width=20mm,
      inner sep=0pt,
      shape=signal,
      signal to=east,
      signal pointer angle=110,
      % fill=blue!50,
      top color=green!60!black!90!,
      bottom color=green!30,
      drop shadow,
    },
  }

  \begin{scope}[start chain=going right,node distance=1mm]
    \node[name=sept3, sign,on chain, minimum width=30mm] {Sept.};
    \foreach \mois / \Smois in
    {
      oct3/Oct., nov3/Nov., dec3/Déc.
    } \node[name=\mois, arrow, minimum width=30mm,on chain, font=\small] {\Smois};

  \node[sign, name=ideation, above=(0mm of sept3.north west),
  anchor=south west,
  font=\small, minimum width=2*30mm+1mm, top color=brown!30!black!90,
  bottom color=brown!30,] {Idéation};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Because `minimum width=2*30mm+1mm`?

Comment: yes : "sept" : 30 mm, "Oct" : 30 mm and distance between node on chaine : 1mm, so I think it good, isn't it ?

Comment: oct is not 30 because of the dent I think

Comment: The `minimum width` is not calculated the same way in both cases of `sign` and `arrow`. Change `arrow` to `sign` and you will find they are now aligned.

Comment: @AboAmmar, It's not working. And I want to start the chain that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As has been already pointed in comments, `sept3` is  a `sign` and `oct3` is an `arrow` and although their `minimum width` is the same, the distance between `oct3.east` and `setp3.west` is not `2*minimum width` because `sign` nodes are "inserted" inside `arrow` left side.

A possible solution for your scheme could be using `let` to calculate a new `minimum width`, with

```
\draw let \p1=($(oct3.east)-(sept3.west)$), \n2={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in ...
```

`\n2` will contain desired minimum distance which must be corrected with `\pgflinewidth`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,scopes,positioning,backgrounds,shapes,fit,shadows,
calc}

\begin{document}
\noindent

\begin{tikzpicture}[background rectangle/.style={draw=blue!50,fill=blue!10,
      rounded corners=5pt, drop shadow},
    show background rectangle]
    \tikzset
    {
      arrow/.style=
      {
        draw,
        minimum height=10mm,
        minimum width=20mm,
        inner sep=0pt,
        shape=signal,
        signal from=west,
        signal to=east,
        signal pointer angle=110,
        top color=green!60!black!90!,
        bottom color=green!30,
        % fill=blue!50,
        drop shadow,
      },
      sign/.style={
      draw,
      minimum height=10mm,
      minimum width=20mm,
      inner sep=0pt,
      shape=signal,
      signal to=east,
      signal pointer angle=110,
      % fill=blue!50,
      top color=green!60!black!90!,
      bottom color=green!30,
      drop shadow,
    },
  }


  \begin{scope}[start chain=going right,node distance=1mm]
    \node[name=sept3, sign,on chain, minimum width=30mm, anchor=west] {Sept.};
    \foreach \mois / \Smois in
    {
      oct3/Oct., nov3/Nov., dec3/Déc.
    } \node[name=\mois, arrow, minimum width=30mm,on chain, font=\small] {\Smois};

    \draw let \p1=($(oct3.east)-(sept3.west)$), \n2={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in  
  node[sign, name=ideation, above=(0mm of sept3.north west),
  anchor=south west,
  font=\small, minimum width=\n2-\pgflinewidth, top color=brown!30!black!90,
  bottom color=brown!30,] {Idéation};
\end{scope}
\draw (0,-1) grid (6,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also correct for that `inset` in the `arrow` shape like this (with some easy trigonometry):

```
minimum width=2*30mm+1mm - 5mm/tan(55) + 1\pgflinewidth
```

which gives the right width as the image below.

[image]